Calculating equivalent resistance of a beautifully "symmetric" circuit




In the given circuit, we have to find the resistances between A and B.

I like to solve such problems by first finding out points which are equipotential, as resistors between such points are redundant and we can essentially remove them from the problem.
Let the points having the same colour indicate points having the same potential.

Since $\Delta V$ across resistances $R_{1},R_{2},R_{3}, R_{4}$ is $0$, they are redundant and we can remove them from the problem. We can also remove paths of wire (without resistances) across which  $\Delta V$ is $0$.
This gives us the following circuit:

To calculate the resistance of this circuit is fairly trivial.
For the resistors nearest to A, we take $R$ and $R$ to be in series, and $2R$ and $R$ to be in parallel, hence equivalent resistance is $\dfrac{2R}{3}\;\;\;$ ($\dfrac{2R \times R}{2R + R}$)

Taking $\dfrac{2R}{3}, R, R\;\;$ in series, equivalent resistance is $\dfrac{8R}{3}$.

After this, we get the equivalent parallel resistance to be $\dfrac{4R}{7}$ ($\dfrac{\frac{4R}{3} \times R}{\frac{4R}{3} + R}$).

Taking $\dfrac{4R}{7}$ and $R$ in series, we get the equivalent resistance as $\dfrac{11R}{7}$!

Hence, we have found the equivalent resistance of the circuit as $\dfrac{11R}{7}$.
But sadly, this seems to be quite far from the correct answer, which is $\dfrac{9R}{20}$.
After going through my procedure once again, I cannot tell where I've gone wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated.

naturallyInconsistent beat me to it, but I'll post this anyway since I have an image that might help.
From your second image to your third image, while removing the shorted resistors, you have also removed some branches by mistake. When removing a resistor whose two terminals are at the same potential, you need to replace it with a short circuit, not an open circuit.
See the correct circuit below. This is still fairly simple to analyze, especially if you make use of the symmetry about the horizontal line $AB$.


Take my upvote, wholesome one

You started out exactly correct, but in your erasing of the wires, you went too far and erased some important connections.
Your first "equivalent circuit" is already wrong. But that is basically all that is wrong. The rest of the argument is correct.
You should erase and replace the centre vertical line of two resistors by wires. Then the left side and the right side are separate; the relationship between left and right are series connection, whereas within the left side, and within the right side, you have parallel resistors.
Once you compute the equivalent resistances for the left side and right side, and then combine them, you will obtain the correct answer as in the answer key. Your analysis method is essentially correct, so you should have no difficulties getting there.
